# How to manage big files upload in L5 class Storage using Flysystem package?

Tags: php, ftp, filesystems, laravel-5, storage

In my Laravel 5 set up, I included the Flysystem package, configured a disk  in config/filesystems.php (ftp)

```
'ftp' => [
        'driver' => 'ftp',
        'host'      => env('FTP_HOST'),
                    'username'  => env('FTP_USER'),
                    'password'  => env('FTP_PASS'),
                    'passive' => TRUE,
    ],
```

Then I'm able to perform ftp upload and download with the following 
instructions:

```
Storage::disk('ftp')->put($filePath, $contents);
Storage::disk('ftp')->get($filePath);
```

Until here everything is fine.
Problems start when I'm uploading big files. Above 200MB. 
PHP memory limit is reached and execution stops with fatal error.
In fact when Storage->put is called my PC memory increases dramatically.

I've read somewhere that a solution might be to use Streams to perform read write from my "virtual" disk.

Actually I'm still missing how to implement it in order to optimize memory usage during these operations.

Comment: Funny thing is that the file is uploaded successfully, but right after it completes i get a error : [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]                                
  Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 603294263 bytes)

Comment: what is your current implementation of upload function? Have you checked out this recipe? http://flysystem.thephpleague.com/recipes/

Comment: As I said I'm using L5 Storage class : Storage::disk('ftp')->put($filePath, $contents); and it works.